# Excel - define range based on identical values

Tags: excel

I need to have Excel look down a column and define 
range by identical (they will be adjacent) cell values, and 
then return text value 'Close' or "open"" based on date 
criteria (of a defined range which would be the same size adjacent to the identical values range excel selects) .  The only condition that should return value of closed is when the date for EVERY asset associated with
each discrete work order is greater than 12/31/2018.

there could be just a single asset (test 
date) for a corresponding work order, or there could be 
even up to 19 dates, that each must be greater than 
12/31/18 in order to 'close'.
would I need a macro to do this or can a formula be written
to return text value in the cell that says CLOSE/OPEN ?
Don't know where to begin, my data set is 30,000 rows

Edit - here's a link to a scaled down version of the sheet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VDhjIO1im2bVhteW8wTElDbVNYSVh6NWxUaEtoMi16Q2RZ/view?usp=drivesdk

Thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do in your question, but it sounds like you're trying to describe an `IF` formula here

Comment: I really just need to have excel define ranges for me based on identical values that are adjacent to each other going down a single column.  From there, can probably work it out.

Comment: So... `IF(A1=B1, "Do this" , "Or do that")` ...? How much research did you do?

Comment: Could you post a link to a google spreadsheet that has an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Link added to original post

Answer (score 0):

> "would I need a macro to do this or can a formula be written"

A formula will be sufficient.

Try put this @ D2

```
=IF(VALUE(DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)))>VALUE(DATE(2018,12,31)),"CLOSE","OPEN")
```

Then drag it downwards.

Happy Learning. (:

---

p/s: web search + EXCEL HELP keyword : "date comparison in excel" if() date() function.

---

Comment: Thanks, I believe that would get around the need to make a table in following answer that was provided internally (at work).  I will give it a shot, but as can be seen in the following answer, the real need is to be able to define each range of dates based on a corresponding work order number, and then look for the oldest date within that range.  The ranges will be different sizes based on how many assets a specific work order holds.

Comment: "be able to define each range of dates based on a corresponding work order number," <---- we can use `index()` + `match()` || "and then look for the oldest date within that range." <---- we can use `max()` || We can start with an example.. would you mind sharing a case? Eg. base on the workorder number _,   we can see that the date is _ at _ cell, and cell _ . So we want select the _  date and put/add it at cell _ . || p/s : you can edit your question instead of putting it here in the comment. ( :

Answer (score 0):

This is the interim answer or work around that was provided to me internally, from a friend.  His solution isn't very elegant, it's time consuming and has to be 'redone' periodically manually.  But it certainly worked.

"this is my suggestion. Here’s what I did:
Create a table with all your data in it.
Choose the headings of R and S, and on the Data tab, select Sort. From here, sort the data first by work order number, and then by date (oldest to newest). 
Click Remove Duplicates, keep the adjacent data, and check only the box next to Emax Work Order.
Add a formula that compares it to the date.
 
**The logic here is that excel will now keep only the first instance of a work order, which corresponds to the oldest date.** If that oldest date is past the end of this year, then all proceeding dates would also, and that work order can be closed. If you need a more specific solution or have questions, let me know.
 
Regards.. "

So all of that is now updated periodically on a separate worksheet, and then I have to use vLookup to get the info back into the original sheet because it's been scaled down to show only one instance of each work order.